# Automatically generate go bindings to a c++ library

Tags: c++, c, go, swig, cgo

I am working on [a program](https://github.com/prologin/stechec2) which from a c++ code generates a `.so` and bindings for multiple languages (C, C++, Haskell, Java, Php, Python...) and I'm trying to add support for golang.
I think the best way to get that result is to either use the C++ or the C version and create go bindings, but this has to be done automatically. I've tried using [Swig](https://github.com/swig/swig) but I didn't manage to get it working (likely because we're including a `.so` and not a `.cc`) and I've only found [old documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/Go.html#Go) (this uses `go tool 6g`).
I've also tried creating bindings with `cgo` which doesn't work with C++, and I couldn't get it working with the C bindings (again, most likely because of the `.so` step).
At the end, I must generate another `.so` with a few exported functions, and which must be standalone which makes compiling the C++ version and talking with it through a pipe (almost?) impossible.
The functions to export are often things like:

```c
void init_game(void);
void play_turn(void);
void end_game(void);
```

You can find a c++ header [here](https://pastebin.com/VLCC4pPQ) and the auto-generated interfaces to C: [interface.hh](https://pastebin.com/v1mVaN4h) and [interface.cc](https://pastebin.com/5nUkmnc3) and [prologin.h](https://pastebin.com/yHij3DyP).
An example source code of `lib.so` can be found [here](https://github.com/prologin/stechec2/tree/master/games/tictactoe/src).

Comment: you might check that blog post to get some ideas https://medium.com/mysterium-network/golang-c-interoperability-caf0ba9f7bf3

Comment: I think they had a manual edition step, so I think I cant do it their way.

Comment: please consider your question might be too broad and that some reproducible code example of the various methods employed could help to motivate others in helping you. It is hard to talk about code we cannot read.

Comment: Also, consider posting the ".h" file that include prototypes for the functions to be exposes (self contained), so that the scope of questions is more clear. It too generic in the current form

Comment: Well, the function to import or expose can depend on the project (that's why the conversion has to be automated), but I'll try to add an example.

Comment: "cgo which doesn't work with C++", how come ? I know several go projects that work with C++, for example https://github.com/hybridgroup/gocv, checkout maybe their source code to get some inspiration